# What shall I do while waiting in a thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio, multithreading

I have a main program which creates a collection of N child threads to perform some calculations. Each child is going to be fully occupied on their tasks from the moment their threads are created till the moment they have finished. The main program will also create a special (N+1)th thread which has some intermittent tasks to perform. When certain conditions are met (like a global variable takes on a certain value) the special thread will perform a calculation and then go back to waiting for those conditions to be met again. It is vital that when the N+1th thread has nothing to do, it should not slow down the other processors.
Can someone suggest how to achieve this.

**EDIT:**
The obvious but clumsy way would be like this:

```
// inside one of the standard worker child threads...
if (time_for_one_of_those_intermittent_calculations_to_be_done())
{
    global_flag_set = TRUE;
}
```

and

```
// inside the special (N+1)th thread
for(;;)
{
    if (global_flag_set == TRUE)
    {
        perform_big_calculation();
        global_flag_set = FALSE;
    }
    // sleep for a while?
}
```

Comment: Can you set a waithandle when the conditions for the N+1 thread is ready?

Comment: You could try to use a counting semaphore - if you implement a user-space version, it will only hit the OS when it actually has to sleep.  Also, you will need the (N+1) thread to have a higher (or at least equal) priority to the N child threads if they are running 100% of the time or you will starve your intermittent service thread.

Comment: If you look at the *Event() functions, combined with WaitForSingleObject/WaitForMultipleObjects, all of the above becomes unnecessary. No "sleep for a while", no deadlocks or need to synchronize changing the global_flag_set using a critical section or mutex or anything else. You really should read the answers people are writing for you...

Comment: I'm delighted to read almost anything other than MSDN. MSDN uses a huge amount of jargon. I find that when I start reading it I end up following the text around in a complex maze trying to find the definitions of all the jargon it introduces. It seems that every page in MSDN assumes that you have read every single other page first!

Comment: @Mick: If you're going to work on Windows at a level other than VBA, you'll need to come to terms with both MSDN and the "jargon". You can't expect other people to write all your code and do all your work for you.

Comment: @ken: saying "check out the WaitForSingleObject" is just not specific enough to be a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ready-to-use condition class for WIN32 ;)

```
class Condition {
private:
    HANDLE m_condition;
    Condition( const Condition& ) {} // non-copyable
public:
    Condition() {
        m_condition = CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL );
    }
    ~Condition() {
        CloseHandle( m_condition );
    }
    void Wait() {
        WaitForSingleObject( m_condition, INFINITE );
        ResetEvent( m_condition );
    }
    bool Wait( uint32 ms ) {
        DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject( m_condition, (DWORD)ms );
        ResetEvent( m_condition );
        return result == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
    }
    void Signal() {
        SetEvent( m_condition );
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
// inside one of the standard worker child threads...
if( time_for_one_of_those_intermittent_calculations_to_be_done() ) {
    global_flag_set = TRUE;
    condition.Signal();
}


// inside the special (N+1)th thread
for(;;) {
    if( global_flag_set==FALSE ) {
        condition.Wait(); // sends thread to sleep, until signalled
    }
    if (global_flag_set == TRUE) {
        perform_big_calculation();
        global_flag_set = FALSE;
    }
}
```

NOTE: you have to add a lock (e.g. a critical section) around `global_flag_set`. And also in most cases the flag should be replaced with a queue or at least a counter (a thread could signal multiple times while 'special' thread is performing its calculations).

Comment: Fantastic job. I assume it will work (I can't test it right now). Thank you.

Comment: You should edit the example usage to include the use of the lock.  Conditions without locks will appear to work, but fail periodically in the manner characteristic of most subtle threading bugs.  The example as it stands is dangerous.

Comment: I know. And the original class is a class MutexCondition containing a mutex and a condition and has pthread semantics (i.e. a wait() requires a lock() before it). I shortened it for using it here. But well, its bed-time for me.. he can figure it out himself. Or ask me again.

Comment: @quark: if by "use of the lock" you mean wrapping reads and writes of global_flag_set within Enter/LeaveCriticalSection()'s then that's Ok, I know how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

You should check out the WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects functions in the Windows API.

[WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have no doubt that this is the right answer, but Microsoft documentation isn't exactly user friendly, and it almost never gives examples. Do you know of anywhere that I could see an example of the code in action?

Comment: I was able to figure out how to use these last summer during an internship using this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687055%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Mick: I find the Microsoft documentation is usually programmer friendly, if not user friendly. Look for keywords and go up levels to find summaries in MSDN. You want to "wait" for some "event" so that your threads are "synchronized." So you follow the links around and pop up levels until you come to Synchronization Objects which has a very nice summary of everything useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use condition variables. If you sleep on a condition variable, the thread will be removed from the runqueue until the condition variable has been signaled.

Answer (score 2):

You should use Windows synchronization events for this, so your thread is doing nothing while waiting. See MSDN for more info; I'd start with [CreateEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx), and then go to the rest of the Event-related functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686360(VS.85).aspx) for [OpenEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684305(VS.85).aspx), [PulseEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684914(VS.85).aspx), [SetEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686211(VS.85).aspx) and [ResetEvent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685081(VS.85).aspx).

And, of course, [WaitForSingleObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032(VS.85).aspx) or [WaitForMultipleObjects()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687025(VS.85).aspx), as pointed out by mrduclaw in the comment below.

Comment: These functions with WaitForMultipleObjects/WaitForSingleObject is the way I'd go.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the more preferred options already given, I generally just yield the CPU in a loop until the desired condition is met.

Comment: "yield the CPU"... what does that mean in practice?

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what it means in practice. Threads are normally scheduled for equal time within a process, which in turn is scheduled equal time among other processes. Yielding the CPU literally means giving up your scheduled slice because you have nothing to do. Not as efficient as only being scheduled on an event, but works in limited environments without any loss in response time (unlike "sleep"ing).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two possibilities for your N+1th thread.

- If its work is rare, the best thing to do is simply to ask it to sleep, and wake it up on demand. Rare context switches are insignificants.
- If it has to work often, then you may need to spinlock it, that is, a busy waiting state that prevent it from being rescheduled, or switched.

Answer (score 0):

Each global variable should have an accompanying event for your N+1 thread. Whenever you change the status of the global variable, set the event to the signaled state. It is better to hide these variables inside a singleton-class private properties and expose functions to get and set the values. The function that sets the value will do the comparison and will set the events if needed. So, your N+1 thread will just to the loop of WaitForMultipleObjects with infinite timeout. Another global variable should be used to signal that the application as a whole exits, so the threads will be able to exit. You may only exit your application after your last thread has finished. So, if you need to prematurely exit, you have to notify all your threads that they have to exit. Those threads that are permanently running, can be notified by just reading a variable periodically. Those that are waiting, like the N+1 thread, should be notified by an event.

People have suggested to use CreateEvent (to create auto-reset events), SetEvent and WaitForMultipleObjects. I agree with them.
Other people have suggested, in addition to the above functions, to use ResetEvent and PulseEvent. I do not agree with them. You don’t need ResetEvent with auto-reset events. This is the function supposed to be used with manual-reset events, but the application of the manual-reset events is very limited, you will see below.

To create an auto-reset event, call the CreateEvent Win32 API function with the bManualReset parameter set to FALSE (if it is TRUE, the function creates a manual-reset event object, which requires the use of the ResetEvent function to set the event state to non-signaled – this is not what you need). If this parameter is FALSE, the function creates an auto-reset event object, and system automatically resets the event state to non-signaled after a single waiting thread has been released, i.e. has exited from a function like WaitForMultipleObjects or WaitForSigleObject – but, as I wrote before, only one thread will be notified, not all, so you need one event for each of the threads that are waiting. Since you are going to have just one thread that will be waiting, you will need just one event.

As about the PulseEvent – it is unreliable and should never be used -- see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684914(v=vs.85).aspx
Only those threads are notified by PulseEvent that are in the "wait" state at the moment PulseEvent is called. If they are in any other state, they will not be notified, and you may never know for sure what the thread state is. A thread waiting on a synchronization object can be momentarily removed from the wait state by a kernel-mode Asynchronous Procedure Call, and then returned to the wait state after the APC is complete. If the call to PulseEvent occurs during the time when the thread has been removed from the wait state, the thread will not be released because PulseEvent releases only those threads that are waiting at the moment it is called. You can find out more about the kernel-mode Asynchronous Procedure Calls (APC) at the following links:
 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951(v=vs.85).aspx
 - http://www.drdobbs.com/inside-nts-asynchronous-procedure-call/184416590
 - http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=75
You can get more ideas about auto-reset events and manual reset events from the following article:
 - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39040/Auto-and-Manual-Reset-Events-Revisited

As about the the Manual-Reset events, they too can be used under certain conditions and in certain cases. You can reliably use them when you need to notify multiple instances of a global state change that occurs only once, for example application exit.

You just have one waiting thread, but maybe in future you will have more waiting threads, so this information will be useful.

Auto-reset events can only be used to notify one thread (if more threads are waiting simultaneously for an auto-reset event and you set the event, just one thread will exit and resets it, and the behavior of other threads will be undefined). From the Microsoft documentation, we may assume that only one thread will exit while others would not, this is not very clear. However, we must take the following quote into consideration: “Do not assume a first-in, first-out (FIFO) order. External events such as kernel-mode APCs can change the wait order” Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682655(v=vs.85).aspx

So, when you need to very quickly notify all the threads – just set the manual-reset event to the signaled state (by calling the SetEvent), rather than signaling each auto-reset event for each thread. Once you have signaled the manual-reset event, do not call ResetEvent since then. The drawback of this solution is that the threads need to have an additional event handle passed in the array of their WaitForMultipleObjects. The array size is limited, although to MAXIMUM_WAIT_OBJECTS which is 64, and in practice we did never reach close to this limit.

At the first glance, Microsoft documentation may seem to be full of jargon, but over time you will find it very easy and friendly. Anyway, correct multi-threaded work is not an easy topic, so you have to tolerate a certain amount of jargon